# Form data processing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and now trying to write a small project in Rails. As part of this project I want to process a form Data(Password). My form is

```
<form name="input" action="http://0.0.0.0:3000/submit/" method="get">

Password: <input type="text" name="password" />

<input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

If the entered password is correct I want to display another html page, the original password is not stored in Database, means just want to compare against a character string. I created a controller and view by using 'rails generate controller project'. I think the code for password match should be written in the file 'project_controller.rb' in 'app/controllers' directory. But how to write code for password match and how to map the url in 'routes.rb' file ? If 'get' method changed to 'post' what are the necessary changes required ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all routes.rb are file to map url to a function on controller

the basic example of routing is like here

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
  get '/form'  => 'project#form'
  get '/submit'  => 'project#submit'
  get '/logedin'  => 'project#logedin'
end
```

there I have 3 function in my project_controller.rb which map to a function
you can change it to post by changing the 'get' to 'post'

here is the example code of the project_controller.rb

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
def form
    #will render view/project/form.html.erb
end

def submit
    if params[:password] == 'secret'
        redirect_to '/logedin'
    else
        #you can redirect to form again 
        #or render the form again
        render 'form' #render the view/project/form.html.erb
    end
end

def logedin
    render :text  => 'you are loged in'
end
```

end

form function will just render the default view which is in app/view/project/form.html.erb

submit is the main logic. you can access the form data using variabel caled **params**

the code is straight forward. you can learn the details on rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: i don't think its a good practice to specify form and submit in the routes.. rather it is better to name the method in controller and view with same name and do the redirecting and displaying notice from controller

Comment: Thank you ahmy. Your code is correct and worked perfectly. It helped me a lot. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes i know this is not the best practice. you should use form using helper and use resource route as much as possible. this example is just to show the rails mechanism dealing with request and route that request to a function.

Comment: Hi ahmy can you give an answer for my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882207/how-link-to-mechanism-works-in-ruby-on-rails