# How link_to mechanism works in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I implemented the official [Creating the Blog Application](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) project as per the directions given. But I am not getting the idea of `link_to` used in this project like:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

given in `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` file, also corresponding code in `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb` for rendering html pages in `app/views/posts/` directory.

If I want to render a new html page say `index2.html.erb` in `app/views/posts/` directory that does not have 'Edit' and 'Destroy' links compared to `index.html.erb`, then how should I write `link_to` and corresponding code in `posts_controller.rb` ?

Comment: probably you should check config/routes.rb

Comment: also try running rake routes, in console from rails apps root folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an action called `index2`, say for a example URL like `http://localhost:3000/posts/index2`, then you need to:

1. Create an action (method) for it in the `posts_controller.rb`:

   ```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController
     ...
     def index2
     end
     ...
   end
   ```
2. Create a view file for it in the `app/views` directory called `index2.html.erb`
3. Add a route to `config/routes.rb`, for example:

   ```
   resources :posts do
     member do
       get 'index2'
     end
   end
   ```

To link to the newly created `index2` page, add a link in some other `html.erb` file to it like this:

```
link_to "index 2",index2_post_path
```

I highly recommend the book [Agile Web Development with Rails (Pragmatic Programmers)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean by writing link_to and corresponding code in post_controller.rb

The link_to mechanism can be simplified like this:

```
link_to('whatever you want to display in the link',{:controller => 'corresponding controller name',:action => 'corresponding action name'})
```

As far as rendering a different template is concerned simply go the controller and write this:

> render('controllername/view')

Hope this will help

Comment: i have written the exact same code but it says ===>>> No route matches {:controller=>"home", :action=>"newBook"}